# Maximizing the sum of rotated vectors

Tags: optimization

I came across an optimization problem as
\begin{equation*}
\underset{\{\theta_i\}_{i=1}^n}{\max}\quad\left\Vert\mathbf{y}+\sum_{i}^ne^{\jmath\theta_i}\mathbf{x}_i\right\Vert,
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are $m$-dimensional vectors. I wonder if there exists global optimal solution to this problem.

Comment: What is $\jmath$?

Comment: Are $\mathbf {x}_i$ and $\mathbf y$ arbitrary? Is $j$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: @RohitPandey It is the imaginary unit

Comment: @YiFan, yes, $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{y}$ can be arbitrary complex vectors but not optimisation variables. It seems the problem is to maximise the norm of sum of n+1 vectors, while one is fixed and others can be rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of complex numbers of the form $e^{\imath \theta}$ are exactly the complex numbers whose absolute value is $1$. Hence, your optimization problem can be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\mathbf{z}} &\quad \| \mathbf{X} \mathbf{z} + \mathbf{y} \| \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad |z_i| = 1 &i = 1, \dots, n
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathbf{X}$ is the matrix whose columns are the vectors $\mathbf{x}_i$. Looking at the real decision variables $\Re(z_i)$ and $\Im(z_i)$, this is a very hard optimization problem which has no known globally optimal solution method, except for, maybe, branch and bound methods (which may be very slow).